Logs Not Displaying Inside WebSocket Connection
I'm integrating Yandex SpeechKit for speech-to-text recognition  in my application. I'm following the documentation provided by Yandex: https://yandex.cloud/en/docs/speechkit/stt/api/streaming-examples#node_1
The connection is working, but I'm facing an issue where the logs related to the recognition process are not being displayed in the console.
Please help
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const fs = require('fs');
const grpc = require('grpc');
const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');

const apiKey = '**************';

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

// Load Yandex STT service proto file
const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync('../yandex/cloud/ai/stt/v2/stt_service.proto', {
    includeDirs: ['node_modules/google-proto-files', '..']
});
const packageObject = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);
const serviceConstructor = packageObject.yandex.cloud.ai.stt.v2.SttService;
const grpcCredentials = grpc.credentials.createSsl(fs.readFileSync('./roots.pem'));
const service = new serviceConstructor('stt.api.cloud.yandex.net:443', grpcCredentials);

// Set up gRPC metadata
const serviceMetadata = new grpc.Metadata();
serviceMetadata.add('authorization', `Api-Key ${apiKey}`);

// Yandex STT request configuration
const requestConfig = {
    config: {
        specification: {
            languageCode: 'ru-RU',
            profanityFilter: true,
            model: 'general',
            partialResults: true,
            audioEncoding: 'LINEAR16_PCM',
            sampleRateHertz: 8000 // Ensure it's a number, not a string
        },
    }
};

let audioInput = [];
let recognizeStream = null;
process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
});

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    console.log('WebSocket connection established');
    // Create a writable stream
    var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('myBinaryFile');
    // Clear the current audioInput
    audioInput = [];
    // Initiate stream recognizing
    recognizeStream = service['StreamingRecognize'](serviceMetadata);

    recognizeStream.write(requestConfig)

    recognizeStream.on('data', (response) => {
        console.log('Start chunk: ');
        response.chunks[0].alternatives.forEach((alternative) => {
            console.log('Received transcription: ', alternative.text);
            ws.send(alternative.text);
            process.stdout.write(`Transcription: ${alternative.text}\n`);
        });
        console.log('Is final: ', Boolean(response.chunks[0].final));
        console.log('');
    });

    recognizeStream.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('gRPC Stream Error:', err);
        ws.close();
    });

    recognizeStream.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Recognition stream ended');
    });

    ws.on('close', () => {
        console.log('WebSocket connection closed');
        wstream.end();
        recognizeStream.end();
    });

    ws.on('message', (message) => {
        try {
            let data = JSON.parse(message);
            if (data.event === "media") {
                let b64data = data.media.payload;
                let buff = Buffer.from(b64data, 'base64');
                recognizeStream.write({ audioContent: buff });
                wstream.write(buff);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error processing message:', err);
            console.log('Message content:', message);
        }
    });

    ws.send('Hi there, I am a WebSocket server');
});

server.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});


The problem is not with the authorization, as I've tested it with a simple example and it works fine. The issue is specifically with displaying logs
Logs regarding to ws are working. Issue regarding to recognizeStream logs

FYI, the grpc package has been deprecated for years. The recommended replacement is @grpc/grpc-js, which mostly has the same APIs. To use it, it should be enough to install it and change the require line to const grpc = require('@grpc/grpc-js');.
